# Hibernate reverse engineering tables to entity class conversion

Tags: hibernate

How to convert list of database table into hibernate entity without creating class or entity manually. is there way to convert list of tables into entity class ?

Comment: How can entity exist without a class?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate reverse engineering tools.

> http://hibernate.org/tools/

And here is a fresh tutorial using mySQL and Eclipse

> http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/java-hibernate-reverse-engineering-tutorial-with-eclipse-and-mysql